# Tor Browser + Privoxy: how to make them work together?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

TBB 6.0.8, Privoxy 3.0.26

What I did - in the Privoxy configuration file prescribed

> listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
>
> forward-socks4 / 127.0.0.1:9150 .
>
> forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:9150 .
>
> forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9150 .
>
> forward-socks5t / 127.0.0.1:9150 .

In browser settings, connection settings, HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS5 - 127.0.0.1:8118

As a result, any page shows me - "Could not find proxy server"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your privoxy config is wrong and will leak. Don't use privoxy with Tor Browser, it *will* harm your anonymity and privacy.

Comment: What configuration can I use? Or any non-permissible?

Comment: You should use a single proxy definition, using all 4 is likely to cause it to make a mistake, socks4 doesn't support remote hostname lookup and will cause it to perform DNS lookups locally, leaking the hosts you try to visit to your DNS server. socks5t is intended for tor usage. socks4a, socks5 or socks5t should be used. socks5t is intended for use with Tor: http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html

Comment: However, as I understand it Tor Browser will resist attempts to subvert it from using it's chosen proxy and so you may not be able to get the http proxy to work. And even if you *did* get it to work, you'll also make your requests look different from other Tor Browser users and lose the circuit isolation that Tor Browser provides. You should not do this, it does not improve Tor Browser.

Comment: My idea was - to put at the end of the chain a transparent proxy, because now it is impossible to make built-in means ... I started with a simple, with an attempt to "make friends" the TBB and Privoxy.

Comment: What properties or functionality do you think privoxy is providing that isn't already done better by Tor Browser? Why do you want it at all?

Comment: IP-addresses are banned in some services.

Comment: This won't end well...do not proceed with this plan. You've been warned, I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: It is a pity that you are gone, I would still ask an embodiment Polipo / Vidalia

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser Bundle to my knowledge doesn't use any TCP anymore, but uses a Unix Socket to communicate with Tor. This means that connecting to Privoxy the way you suggest is impossible.

I also think that `127.0.0.1` might refer to the exit node (and in that case is forbidden).

Your only option might be to use a more custom setup.

Comment: It still uses TCP

Comment: @canonizingironize In the torrc of Tor browser I have my ControlPort and SocksPort both set to unix sockets, so I don't think that's true - even though it might still support TCP.

Comment: Are you using the alpha? A fresh 6.0.8 has `SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth` and `ControlPort 9151` in `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults`, at least on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Yes, I do. Feels ages since I first read that in the changelog. Thought it was in stable meanwhile. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I realized that Privoxy conflicts with Torbutton. What needs to change in the Torbutton, to remove this conflict?